# Shopify API App Proxy with Rails verify Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, shopify

I am trying to configure an app proxy so users can submit a product for a Shopify store.  I have seen multiple ways to so a signature and handle it so yet I am unable to get it working so the ShopifyAPI will work.  The action is below, I noticed that:shopify_session filter only works for admin, not customers as well.

```
def submit_product
    query_parameters = Rack::Utils.parse_query(request.query_string)

    # Remove and save the "signature" entry
    signature = query_parameters.delete("signature")
    sorted_params = query_parameters.collect{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{Array(v).join(',')}" }.sort.join
    calculated_signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha256'), ENV['SHOPIFY_SECRET'], sorted_params)
    raise 'Invalid signature' if signature != calculated_signature
    @store = Store.where(shopify_url: query_parameters['shop']).first 
    if @store.present?
      @product = @store.products.new
      @product.images.build
      @product_types = ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find(@store.customizable_collection_id).products
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can connect to the ShopifyAPI you should first establish an API session. Otherwise the `ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find` method can't connect to Shopify. Steps 3 and 4 of the [shopify_api README](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api#getting-started) include the following example:

```
session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com", token)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
product_types = ShopifyAPI::CustomCollection.find(id)
```

`token` is the permanent access token which you can request during the [OAuth](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth) Authentication phase (the installation of the App into a shop).

Comment: If using the [shopify_app gem](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_app) how would one get the token?  The app has a shopify_session filter that is used to handle the OAuth so unsure how I would change that.

Comment: Got it working, was trying to create a new action with that information.  Best way is to just edit the show action in the sessions controller.  Thank you!